# Ajustar texto do botão curtir e compartilhar do facebook em página

Tags: javascript, facebook

Tenho em minha página um script que insere o botão Curtir e Compartilhar e o meu site tem característica responsiva e ao ser redimensionado o texto fica sem ajustar na página.
A única coisa que tenho é esse script aqui:

Esqueci de inserir uma div que tenho antes do script, ela está assim:

```
<div id="facebook"></div>
```

```
(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

O exemplo pode ser visto aqui ao redimensionar a página, veja:
[Página com os botões Curtir e Compartilhar](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/detalhes.php?produto=131&dep=2&sub=14)

Comment: Testei aqui e não vi problemas.... Qual navegador está usando?

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft, estou testando no chrome, o texto fica cortado no fim.

Comment: O único texto que cortou desse caso foi o `Cadastre-se para ver do que seus amigos gostam`. É esse que está cortando para você também?

Comment: Sim @RafaelWithoeft, esse também

Comment: Tente criar mediaqueries css, para os botões, no caso a classe e id que você pode sobreescrever são: .pluginButtonContainer {width: 200px; text-align:center} e #u_0_3 {...}; Só adaptar ao seu código e ir testando se vai dar certo. E criar os mediasqueries que no caso não fiz, só demonstrei como poderia ser o css.. o resto fica na sua mão agora...

Comment: Tente colocar em seu código: `#facebook td, td.label {
  display: inline-block;
}` no mediaqueries, acredito que vai resolver.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema adventista?

Comment: Olá @RafaelWithoeft, perdoe a minha ignorância no assunto css, inseri o código sugerido na mediaqueries mas não aconteceu nada, fiz uma edição na pergunta e coloquei a div que vem antes do script, ela está assim nomeada <div id="facebook"></div>

Comment: Não identifico o botão. Somente a div.

Comment: Olá @Lollipop, também não vejo nada sobre botão, somente a div e o javascript.

Comment: Este é o problema? Não aparece nada?

Comment: Os botões aparecem, mas ao browser ser redimensionada o texto: Seja o primeiro de seus amigos a curtir isso.